# How to use multiple values in hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

Say I have this object:

```
myObj = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
            name: 'Frank'
        }
    }
};
```

How can I use `hasOwnProperty()` to check multiple depths of my object. Something like this works:

```
if (myObj.hasOwnProperty('level1') {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty('level2') {
        if (myObj.hasOwnProperty('name') {
            console.log(myObj.level1.level2.name)
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping for something like:

```
myObj.hasOwnProperty(['level1', 'level2', 'name']);
myObj.hasOwnProperty('level1.level2.name);
```

My goal is to not `console.log(myObj.level1.level2.name)` if not all the properties are there, so you can answer this question by providing an alternate for `hasOwnProperty` also.

Answer (score 6):

You could take a closure over the object and check the keys.

```js
const check = o => k => [o.hasOwnProperty(k), o = (o || {})[k]][0];

var myObj = { level1: { level2: { name: 'Frank' } } };

console.log(['level1', 'level2', 'name'].every(check(myObj)));
console.log(['level1', 'level3', 'name'].every(check(myObj)));
```

Comment: Great - but so unreadable :(